# Error upgrading Eclipse Kepler SR1 to SR2?

Tags: java, eclipse

When trying to upgrade Windows 64bit Eclipse Kepler SR1 to SR2, I keep getting the following error (for a week now):

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.adapter,1.1.102.v20130418_1650
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.patch,3.4.2.v20130418_1724-208a7w31241529a2761
```

I am not behind a proxy. Any idea how to solve this?
The screenshot shows the upgrade I want to perform when chosing "Check for update" in the Eclipse help.
I checked my upgrade repo's and think they are correct, especially the wtp url which is:http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler/

[image]

Comment: At a guess it is the WTP Patch line, what is that?

Comment: Don't. Just unzip a new download and tell it to install the plugins found in your old eclipse folder.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: can you give me some more details please? (unzip a complete download?... or just the patch?, will I not loose my current plugin settings?)

Comment: Probably.  I have personally bad experiences with the eclipse update mechanism - I always download a new zip and import from the previous one if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing unnecessary update repo's, followed by a software update which was performed correctly. After restart I performed another software update, and then the WTP patch was installed correctly.

I am not sure which update respo's I removed precisely, but it was some old wtp patch update, and some webshpere update repo. I am not sure how they got there, and if they were there during a clean installation..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

I have redone the update without selecting the patch for WTP. It worked well.
Then, after searching for new upgrades, the patch for WTP had disapeared...

Comment: I tried that last week, but didn't work. It did added the patch for some dependency reason. Maybe I selected too much.

Comment: The same happend to me. In fact in one moment I saw two patches.

Answer (score -1):

I faced issue when doing upgrade for the Android SDK and I fixed the issue differently. Navigate to 'Eclipse Market Place' -> 'Popular' tab -> search for Android SDK - I was presented with 'Update' button to update, and it worked.